# Having two Usernames for the same Active Directory account

Tags: active-directory

Is it possible to have two usernames for the same Active Directory account. Essentially we want the users to be able to login any of the 2 usernames (same account).

Comment: Do you mean have two users share the same profile?

Comment: Title Suggestion: "Is it possible to have two usernames for the same Active Directory account"?

Comment: Why would you want two people to have the same account using two different names?

Comment: @Matt You're aware of [suggested edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284) yes? Also, to which attribute[s] does "usernames" refer?

Comment: @jscott I am aware but I am also unsure what the Op is actually trying to do. If this is an XY issue then I don't want to obfuscate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by "username"?

You can only have one SamAccountName per account, but an account's User Principal Name can be entirely different than the SamAccountName and you can log in with either one.